# Java - generic types

Tags: java

I am trying to create a binary tree using generic typing and I have an error I do not understand.  I tried two ways of coding and the second worked.  I do not understand why the first was failing.

I have the following common code:

```
public class MyTreea <T extends Comparable<T>> 
{     
   class BT_Node<T extends Comparable<T>>
           {
            T           value;
            BT_Node<T>  left;
            BT_Node<T>  right;

            BT_Node(T node_value) 
                  { 
                    this.value   = node_value ;
                    left         = null;
                    right        = null;
                  }
           }
```

The difference is in insert procedure:
This works:

```
 private BT_Node<T> insert(BT_Node<T> node, BT_Node<T> newNode) {
      if ((node.value).compareTo(newNode.value) == 0) { . . . }
```

But this fails

```
  private BT_Node insert(BT_Node node, T value) {
        if (value.compareTo(node.value) == 0) { . .
```

With:

```
MyTreea.java:28: error: method compareTo in interface Comparable<T#2> cannot be applied to given types;
            if (value.compareTo(node.value) == 0)
required: T#1
found: Comparable
reason: actual argument Comparable cannot be converted to T#1 by method invocation conversion
where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
T#1 extends Comparable<T#1> declared in class MyTreea
T#2 extends Object declared in interface Comparable
```

Obviously if I call BT_insert with two nodes parameters it tis fine. (And I code to cater for that by creating an extra function) but I would have preferred not to it this way.

Thanks

Comment: Could you perhaps post the full file, including namespaces and the Comparable class?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the second example with the following signature:

```
private BT_Node<T> insert(BT_Node<T> node, T value)
```

The example you gave uses "raw types" (i.e. a generic class without a generic parameter), which is generally always a bad idea and arguably only exists for backwards compatibility with Java 1.4.  `BT_Node` is a generic class, so you should *always* give it a generic parameter.

In the case where you didn't, this was roughly equivalent to passing in `BT_Node<?>`, in that the Node could have had any value for its generic parameter.  So the compiler could not guarantee that the `value` you were passing in was of the correct type - the first argument could be a `BT_Node<Int>` for example, while `T` is `String`.

By passing in the generic parameter as `T`, the compiler can check that the type of the `value` and the type of the node *do* match.

Answer (score 1):

BT_Node can use T without parametrising it again, remove its T parameter.

Otherwise you have to different Ts which could be different extensions of their Comparable.
Also no `BT_Node<T>`.